# Commenting using Doxygen vs. Custom template

Tags: c, comments, doxygen

I'm building my coding habits using C coding standards to improve consistency. I've heard about Doxygen and it's used widely for generating documentation for software projects. I don't know a lot about Doxygen and don't know how to use it, but I found that I can use it to auto-generate comments for `files` and `functions`. I know it's all about personal preference, but from an expert perspective does it affect generating documentation if I used something for file header like:

```c
/* =================================================================================================================
  FILE DESCRIPTION
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  File        : dio.c
  Category    : drivers - dio
  Date        : 25 Jan. 2023
  Author      : Nabil Yasser
  Git Account : 
  Description : Includes DIO driver functions Implementation for ATmega32
==================================================================================================================== */
```

instead of that includes commands like `@author` and `@date` which Doxygen generates:

```c
/**
 * @file dio.c
 * @author Nabil Yasser
 * @brief 
 * @version 0.1
 * @date 31/01/2023
 * 
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2023
 * 
 */
```

and for functios that's what I'm currently using:

```c
/* =================================================================================================================
 * Syntax      : uint8 dio_setPin(DioPortId_et portId, DioChannelId_et channelId, DioChannelDirection_et direction)
 * Description : Sets DIO pins direction as output or input
 * Sync/Async  : Synchronous
 * Reentrancy  : Non Reentrant
 * Arguments   : portId    : Port name in which the pin you want to set direction for (GPIOA, GPIOB, GPIOC, GPIOD).
 *             : channelId : Name of channel/pin you want to set direction for (PIN0 ~ PIN7)
 *             : direction : Channel/pin direction (INPUT, OUTPUT)
 * Output      : E_OK (0)  : If no problems
 *             : E_NOK (1) : If there is any problem
==================================================================================================================== */
```

versus what generated by Doxygen:

```c
/**
 * @brief function desciption text
 * 
 * @param portId description about parameter
 * @param channelId description about parameter
 * @param direction description about parameter
 * @return uint8 description about return value
 */
```

Can any of these affect my ability to use Doxygen or even generally affect readability for other developers in any possible way? or I'm just okay since they're just comments?

Comment: Any form of commenting code is good, and can only help other developers in understanding your code.

Comment: Your format, with its aligned columns and use of special characters, is difficult and time-consuming to maintain - which means it won't be kept up.  "Space this right! It has to line up! Make this line of `====` the same lenght!  Forget this, I have work to do!"

Comment: _"using C coding standards"_...  What C coding standards?  I have never seen one that has been agreed to (or precisely followed) by more than one person in any organization.  in-line comments are good.  Comment blocks are good. latitude in how they are presented should be tolerated.  Anytime someone has come along with overly prescriptive rules on in-code documentation and then expects people to follow them has resulted in the pot beginning to boil.  If the lid is on too tight, it will pop eventually.

Comment: ...That said, _readability for other developers_ is always appreciated, and if done well has a huge positive impact on maintainability.   But the style or format should not be strictly mandated.

Comment: Why write in C when you can create your own language?

Comment: The main purpose of Doxygen is to produce documentation in different formats, many prefer HTML, from the comments in your source. For this you need to obey Doxygen's syntax. It is "just" a bonus that it can enrich your source with templates.

Comment: @thebusybee so in case to use Doxygen properly I need to comment using commands like `@author` `@file` and `@date` ?

Comment: Yes, read the docs. This lost art is already the best idea, and should be your first tasks, if you investigate such issues.